# Find and prove an equation relating $[T^t]_{B^*}^{B^*}$ and $[(T^t)^t]_{B^{**}}^{B^{**}}$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space over the field $F$ and let $T:V \rightarrow V$ be  $F$-linear.  Suppose $B$ is an $F$-basis for $V$.  Find and prove an equation relating $[T^t]_{B^*}^{B^*}$ and $[(T^t)^t]_{B^{**}}^{B^{**}}$.

I am very confused how to even go about finding such an equation that relates these.  I believe that after finding the equation I will be able to prove that it is true.  Sorry if it seems like I haven't done any work on it, I have no idea how to even go about doing a problem like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't get the point: why just simply ask for a relation between

$$
[T]^B_B \qquad \text{and} \qquad [T^t]^{B^*}_{B^*} \quad \text{?}
$$

(The one you're asking for would follow from that simpler one, wouldn't it?)

In that case, the relation is simple enough:

$$
[T^t]^{B^*}_{B^*} = \left( [T]^B_B  \right)^t
$$

Isn't it?

Remark. I'm assuming that your $T^t$ means the dual of $T$. That is, the linear map $T^t : V^* \longrightarrow V^*$ defined by $T^t\omega = \omega \circ T$. I also assume that your $B^*$ means the dual basis. That is, if $B = \left\{ u_1, \dots , u_n \right\}$ form a basis of $V$, its dual basis is $B^* = \left\{ u_1^*, \dots , u_n^* \right\} $, where the $u_i^* : V \longrightarrow F$ are the linear forms defined by $u_i^*(u_j) = 1 $ if $i =j$ and $0$ otherwise.

If my assumptions are true, I add another piece of standard notation: that $t$ exponent on the right means the *transpose* of the matrix.

So, in order to prove the stated relation, we can proceed as follows: let's call $A = [T]^B_B$ and display its entries

$$
A = 
\begin{pmatrix}
a^1_1   &  \dots & a^1_i  & \dots  & a^1_n  \\
\vdots  &        & \vdots &        & \vdots  \\
a^j_1   & \dots  & a^j_i  & \dots  & a^j_n  \\
\vdots  &        & \vdots &        & \vdots  \\
a^n_1   & \dots  & a^n_i  & \dots  & a^n_n
\end{pmatrix}
$$

This means that

$$
T(u_i) = a^1_i u_1 + \dots + a^j_iu_j + \dots + a^n_i u_n \ .
$$

And since we are saying that $[T^t]^{B^*}_{B^*} = A^t$, what we need to show is

$$
T^t(u^*_j) =  a^j_1 u^*_1 + \dots + a^j_iu^*_i + \dots + a^j_n u^*_n \ ,
$$

for all $j$. Right?

Ok, so now your turn: compute. On one hand, find out

$$
T^t(u^*_j) (u_i) 
$$

for every $i,j$. On the other hand, find out

$$
(  a^j_1 u^*_1 + \dots + a^j_iu^*_i + \dots + a^j_n u^*_n)(u_i) 
$$

too, for all $i,j$. Compare. Think.

Comment: $B^{**}$ is supposed to be the dual basis of the dual basis.  I'm not sure how you are getting B, unless you are doing something like the $(T^t)^t=T$, so then I think I can say it is B is the same as double dual basis of V?

Comment: Yes. Indeed you have that equality and also $(B^*)^* = B$ and $(V^*)^* = V$. In fact, "equality" means "canonical isomorphism", to be precise. You can identify all those double duals with the original guys through the following isomorphism: $\phi : V \longrightarrow V^{**}$, $\phi (u) (\omega) = \omega (u)$.